# Files.createTempDirectory("") throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, windows, nullpointerexception, nio2, tempdir

When I call `Files.createTempDirectory("")` I get the below exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsSecurityDescriptor.fromAttribute(WindowsSecurityDescriptor.java:353)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:220)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:315)
at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:586)
at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:138)
at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile(TempFileHelper.java:161)
at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Files.java:803)
```

None of the examples of the usage of `Files.createTempDirectory("")` I have found passed in any `FileAttribute`s.
I have tried with `Files.createTempDirectory("", new FileAttribute<?>[] { });` but it did not help either.

I am using 32 bit JDK 7 on Windows 7 system.
I am not local admin on the machine.

Has anybody come accross this?

**UPDATE 1:**

`Files.createTempFile(this.tempDir.toPath(), "tmpFile", "");` seems to have the same problem.

As a workaround I have moved to `com.google.common.io.Files.createTempDir()`.

Comment: Just tried it with JDK1.7.0_07, facing no problem. Which one do you use?

Comment: I use 1.7.0_11-b21. Probably it has something to do with the Windows 7 environment at my employer.

Comment: Seems to be still happening in Java 1.8/Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `Files.createTempDirectory(null)` instead of `Files.createTempDirectory("")`. In the documentation, you can read that it's possible pass the prefix as null object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-